# Issue in weblogic server : java.rmi.ConnectException

Tags: java, weblogic, thread-dump

There was a latency observed in server.

While analyzing thread dump I found the below exception,

```
Caused By: java.rmi.ConnectException: Could not establish a connection with -6076537124444815257S:tamp20-pcip-crmapp6.app.net:[6801,6801,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]:tamp20-pcip-crmapp1.app.net:6801,tamp20-pcip-crmapp1.app.net:6802,tamp20-pcip-crmapp2.app.net:6801,tamp20-pcip-crmapp2.app.net:6802,tamp20-pcip-crmapp3.app.net:6801,tamp20-pcip-crmapp3.app.net:6802,tamp20-pcip-crmapp4.app.net:6801,tamp20-pcip-crmapp4.app.net:6802,tamp20-pcip-crmapp5.app.net:6801,tamp20-pcip-crmapp5.app.net:6802,tamp20-pcip-crmapp6.app.net:6801,tamp20-pcip-crmapp6.app.net:6802:crm:clust11, java.rmi.ConnectException: Destination unreachable; nested exception is: 
java.io.IOException: Empty server reply; No available router to destination; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.ConnectException: Destination unreachable; nested exception is: 
java.io.IOException: Empty server reply; No available router to destination
```

Any idea what can be the reason? Can this be triggered with network issue?

If you have faced such issue before, what might have triggered this in weblogic server?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a classical network problem. Can you ping the remote server?

Comment: Run tracert from command shell on that host.